# Run multiple Powershell commands and export results to csv

Tags: powershell, batch-file, export

I'm hoping this is a nice quick one. I have 11 scripts setup to check whether Microsoft Licenses are directly assigned or not. I then have a master.ps1 that will run all these scripts one after the other. What I want to achieve, is to basically export the results from the master.ps1 after it's finished running. All the scripts are the same, the only difference being that the license names change. So for example, checking the EMS license:

```
$skuId = "contoso:SPE_E3"
`Get-MsolUser -All | where {$_.isLicensed -eq $true -and $_.Licenses.AccountSKUID -eq $skuId} | select UserPrincipalName,
@{Name="SkuId";Expression={$skuId}}, 
@{Name="AssignedDirectly";Expression={(UserHasLicenseAssignedDirectly $_ $skuId)}}, 
@{Name="AssignedFromGroup";Expression={(UserHasLicenseAssignedFromGroup $_ $skuId)}}`
```

The master.ps1 will be as follows:

```
&"$PSScriptroot\Script1.ps1"
&"$PSScriptroot\Script2.ps1"
&"$PSScriptroot\Script3.ps1"
```

Etc

I've tried adding Export-CSV after the master file but it doesn't work, can anyone assist please?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using a `ForEach-Object` pipeline:

```
'Script1', 'Script2', 'Script3' | ForEach-Object {
    & "$PSScriptroot\$_.ps1"
} | Export-Csv ...
```

This passes an array literal consisting of the script names to `ForEach-Object`. The output of the `ForEach-Object` script block is then passed to `Export-Csv`, *as it is generated* (a streaming approach).

If you want to keep separate script calls (which might be more straightforward in case the scripts need different arguments), you can create just a script block `{}` and run it immediately, using the [`&` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#call-operator-):

```
& {
    & "$PSScriptroot\Script1.ps1"
    & "$PSScriptroot\Script2.ps1"
    & "$PSScriptroot\Script3.ps1"
} | Export-Csv ...
```

This has the same advantage as the `ForEach-Object` variant above, that it is a *streaming* approach, requiring less memory to store intermediate output (only for internal buffering, independent of the scripts output size).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your capture the output from all the scripts when exporting to CSV:

```
@(
  & "$PSScriptroot\Script1.ps1"
  & "$PSScriptroot\Script2.ps1"
  & "$PSScriptroot\Script3.ps1"
) |Export-Csv ...
```

Alternatively, export the output from each script one at a time, then use `Export-Csv -Append` for subsequent scripts:

```
& "$PSScriptroot\Script1.ps1" |Export-Csv ...
& "$PSScriptroot\Script2.ps1" |Export-Csv -Append ...
& "$PSScriptroot\Script3.ps1" |Export-Csv -Append ...
```

Comment: Note that `@( ... )` collects all output into an in-memory array first, then pipes the whole array to `Export-Csv`. Using a streaming approach like `&{ ... } |Export-Csv ...` would use less memory resources as each scripts output would be passed to `Export-Csv` when it is generated.

Comment: That's exactly what I was after, thanks :)